# cross domain canonical url used over og:url while whatsapp sharing

Tags: facebook-opengraph, canonical-link

We have a number of corporate site and dealer sites for our brand. The domains differ for both. For dealer site I have a **cross domain rel=canonical** (pointing to corporate site) and **og:url(pointing to the current page url of dealer site)**. 
**Ask is that when sharing a page from dealer site on social media forms, the link used must be the og:url(url of the page itself).** Canonical is kept as that of corporate site because of SEO reasons.

But when the dealer site page is shared via whatsapp, the canonical url is used(which is the corporate one). Although on the facebook developer tools, the link preview formed points to current page url. But on the mobile, while sharing,  current page url(og:url) is not shared. Instead the canonical one is used. 
Please let me know why this is happening and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume if you share this from a mobile browser, the browser picks the URL value from the canonical tag.
This would be a "feature" of the mobile browser app and have nothing to do with how Facebook reads the source of your HTML page when scanning it.